# CPU: Program inside CPU that determines exact principal of instructions (?!)

Tags: assembly, cpu, microcoding

At Computer Science lecture we’ve been told that there’s a special code (lower that assembler) that determines behavior of CPU which is written inside CPUs ROM. It was meant that is determines what exactly every instruction in boolean logic means… That sounds quite strange – I haven’t found any kind of information about that.

Probably he meant not CPU but microcontrollers? But he told that it determines exact behavior of such kind of instructions like MOV, ADD ect. So, I am perplexed.

Or he meant any kind of PCB layout language?

Comment: Generally not microcontrollers, burns too much power.  The x86 is well known for having been microcoded, at least for the middle/latter part of its life, it may still be now.  Unfortunately that leads to a myth that all processors are microcoded.  They are not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean microcode?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode

Comment: Interestingly, the floppy disk drive was originally invented as a way of loading microcode for the IBM S/370 mainframe. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_floppy_disk

Comment: @Gabe yes, another interesting historical fact :D

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It seems to be microcode. So, all these SSE, MMX, 3DNow are implemented using microcode?

Comment: As a php programmer, the tool I work with is very high level and allows to program in something _very close to plain english_.  This stuff is in outer space for me! This aspect of computing, the low level stuff, is the part most users ( I included ) take for granted.

Comment: @stefgosselin I guess you're right, thought I like to know how things work :) I'm mostly self taught.